# Changing header "From: noreply@domain.com" to other value, sends mail into spam folder

Tags: php, sendmail

I have this php mail() code on my site, which works fine.

It is an ecard system, my client can fill out the from info (name, email) and to info (name, email), etc and Mail goes straight to Inbox, on google, hotmail, yahoo, etc.

When the receiver gets the email he can use the reply button, and it gets the right info.

The problem is the `From:` header in my mail form, I want to change this from `noreply@example.com` to the receiver's info, or any other info. When I do that, the mail goes into SPAM mail.

Here is the code I'm using

```
<?php

$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$motive = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$name2 = $_REQUEST['name2'] ;
$email2 = $_REQUEST['email2'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
$message =  urldecode(stripslashes($message));

$headers = 'From:' . $name . ' John Q<noreply@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers.= "Reply-To:" .$name. "<" . $motive. ">\n";
$headers.= "Return-Path: My Company<admin@datatopixels.com>\n";
$headers.= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\n";


$messagee = "
<html>
<head>
<title>Title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<br>
</center>
</body>
</html>
";


mail($to, $subject, $messagee, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: You cannot do that, why ? Because that does not depend on your code it depends on the domain holder for the given email you're trying impersonate as. That's exactly why there are things like reverse DNS, DKIM, SPF and other rules to identify that a given server and IP own that domain or that a given SMTP is allowed to send messages as a given email.

Comment: You don't have control over email clients. You never have guarantee that you mail won't be in spam. It depends on filter on the receiving end.

Comment: @chap:Try adding the last parameter in this string at the last line: mail($to, $subject, "My message.. ", $headers, "-f noreply@domain.com");

Comment: Investigate why your e-mail message is classified as spam. Some spam filters put the reason into the mail header. Read [Some Tips for Legitimate Senders to Avoid False Positives](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/AvoidingFpsForSenders).

Comment: Try to change the mail content to more informal way. Some mail servers have some common pattern to move to SPAM.
Also give an additional space in between name and email 'John Q<noreply@example.com>' as '"John Q" <noreply@example.com>'. For some mails it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You must to add a needle headers:

Sample code :

```
$headers = "From: myplace@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: myplace2@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: myplace@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: sombodyelse@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "BCC: hidden@example.com\r\n";

if ( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) ) {
   echo "The email has been sent!";
   } else {
   echo "The email has failed!";
   }
?>
```

And I would suggest to read [oswalds's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935087/how-do-i-prevent-mails-sent-through-php-mail-from-going-to-spam)

Comment: I tried your code above, but it goes to Spam, as soon as I change the "From:" with "noreply@domian.com" , it goes to Inbox. What a pain!

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I don't understand why!

Comment: I tried adding the 5th parameter (-f noreply@domain.com) no luck too. as Samdroid suggested

Comment: OKK...Try PHP Mailer library.
Or Send mail through SMTP filter it before sending it.
Also Try to give all details like FROM, return-path.

Comment: does this mean anything to you?  X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: intovps.datapixels.com: uid via acl_c_vhost_owner from authenticated_id: nobody from /only user confirmed/virtual account not confirmed

Comment: That's what google show in the source email. somehow it does not get my header "Return-Path: someuser@datapixels.com"  it gives me "Return-Path: <nobody@intovps.datapixels.com>"

Comment: read my comment and u will understand why good mail servers will catch your emails as spam when trying to impersonate email's you don't own.