# Sending emails using php/apache - configuring send address

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, php

I have setup an Amazon EC2 instance and trying to send emails using php's `mail()` function. Email sending works fine but the send address contains `apache@ip-XX-XXX-XX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.internal` where `XX` are integers. This causes the email to be classified as spam at the inbox. I have tried using needle headers as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935087/how-do-i-prevent-mails-sent-through-php-mail-from-going-to-spam) with no avail.

I have a domain name pointing to this server and how can I link it to the sending address?

Comment: what software id detecting the email as spam ?

Answer (score -1):

The reason being most of Amazon public IPs are marked as blacklisted. You need to use amazon SNS or SES service to send out emails.

Comment: But if in the `from` address it says `apache@ip-XX-XXX-XX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.internal` it would seem to the spam detector that this is coming from something automated, so it obviously looks like spam. What I am trying to say is that are you sure its because of the blacklisting thing or could it be due to the `from` address

Comment: no you don't i send emails (with the php mail function) from my ec2 machine all the time.

Comment: if you use ec2, how do you prevent it from not going to spam? Can you post an answer pls.