# Emails going to spam

Tags: php, arrays, email

I want to make it so my email script will go to the inbox instead of the spam box.
How can I fix this? 
Here is my code

```
$q_ry = array();
$q_ry = "SELECT `my_email` FROM `members`";
$adresses = array();
$adresses = mysql_query($q_ry);

while ($u = mysql_fetch_array($adresses)) 
{
    if (!mail($u['my_email'],"Reunited City Newsletter",$_POST['email'],"From: no-reply@reunited-city.com")) 
    {
        echo "Email not sent to" . $u['my_email'] . "!<br/>";
    }
}

echo "<font color = 'green'><b>Mass email sent successfully!</b></font>";
```

I can post the complete code if needed..
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935087/how-do-i-prevent-mails-sent-through-php-mail-from-going-to-spam.. this might help you

Comment: i agree with RamRaider. An other reason could be that your Mail-Server is marked as a spam server.

Comment: Oh okay, just annoys me that it goes go spam instead of inbox. My emails never contain spam

Comment: try to send a Mail with "normal" subject from another mail address with your script and see if this works. if not its a server problem.

Comment: Went to spam, I will contact my host