# not able to send mail from php

Tags: php, cpanel

I want to send a email from php mail function. This is my code

```
<?php
  $to = "modiv2301@gmail.com";
  $subject = "HTML email";

  $message = "
       <h1>this is msg</h1>
  ";


  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

  $headers .= 'From: <modiv2301@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
  $success=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
  if (!$success) {
      $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'];
      print_r($errorMessage);
  }else{
      echo "Success";
      $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'];
      print_r($errorMessage);
  }
  ?>
```

when i run this code its showing me Success but i am not Receiving any email

Comment: I think gmail will reject your sender, because it's not authenticated to GMail, but claims to be a gmail sender. You could try to change the sender or try to send to another email account.

Comment: i had changed sender and receiver both mail but problem is still there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent mails sent through PHP mail() from going to spam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935087/how-do-i-prevent-mails-sent-through-php-mail-from-going-to-spam)

Comment: Can you send mail from the command line on that system? The `mail()` function relies on the systems mailing logic to be setup correctly. Check your systems log files for issues too.

Comment: its not showing my mail even in my spam box

Comment: Use a class like PHPMailer.  It takes care of your basic headers for you.  Easy to use install and use.  https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer